# Getting String Name from an Item in a ListView when clicked. Android

Tags: android, listview, getstring

For some reason this only returns the name of the first item in the list no matter which item I click.  I am not sure why it isn't returning the proper name.  Basically I just want to find the name so I can search the list for that name so I can find its location in the array.

```
    myTask.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
            String name = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
            for (int i = 0; i < ToDoActivity.myUser.taskCount; i++){
                if(name == ToDoActivity.myUser.tasks[i].getTaskName())
                    clickTask = i;
            }
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), TaskEdit.class);
            view.getContext().startActivity(myIntent);
        }
```

Thank You
Dlong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you can simply use the `position` argument of `onItemClick`:

```
clickTask = position;
```

Comment: doesn't that refer to the position in the list not the position in the array? What if I sorted the list to only display certain items then the position variable would correspond to the right position in the array right?

Answer (score 0):

Use the "position" value that is being passed to you. It tells you which index was pressed.

Answer (score 0):

replace this line:

```
if(name == ToDoActivity.myUser.tasks[i].getTaskName())
```

with this line:

```
if(name.equals(ToDoActivity.myUser.tasks[i].getTaskName()))
```

Comment: While technically true, Binyamin Sharet's answer is more along the lines of what the user should be doing